# How to Use Preview Frame to Decode a QR using Zxing in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing

I know that questions related to this post have been asked before, but I was unable to find a clear answer. I am a beginner in Android, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me out in a step by step manner.
I have to build an app, that opens a camera and passes its preview frames to Zxing. Zxing has to process each of these frames, and find whether a QR code exists in it or not. 
I have this code snippet, that decodes an image stored in SD card.

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image2.png");
    TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    View webbutton=findViewById(R.id.webbutton);
    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap); 
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    try {
         Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
         Global.text = result.getText(); 
            byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); 
            BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
            ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
            textv.setText(Global.text);
            webbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();


    }   
}
```

I need to integrate it with the preview callbacks, so that instead of the SDcard image, the decoder takes the preview frame. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Any sample code would greatly help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That's about right. You can't use `RGBLuminanceSource` since it is for JavaSE. You need `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource`.

You also need to handle those exceptions. You can use `QRCodeReader` if you are just scanning for QR codes.

Look at the source code for Barcode Scanner, [particularly for DecodeHandler](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android). This shows how you interact with the preview frame. Or it's one way at least.

Comment: I have studied these activities, and they are all inter-dependent. Every time I import the Android folder, so I can use PlanarYUVLuminanceSource, or something else, I get these errors: "R cannot be resolved to a variable." I know that it is because my R.java doesn't contain the id's declared in these activities. How do I fix that?

Comment: Why would you need to copy the entire source? Copy the bit you need here and there. Use `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource`, and the snippet from `DecodeHandler` that you need. No problem.

Comment: camera = Camera.open();  try {  camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

   camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {

Comment: @SeanOwen What is the `data` and `dataWidth`/`dataHeight` you pass to `PlanerYUVLuminanceSource`? I'm using `camera2` with `ImageReader`. The `Image` captured is `YUV_420_888` format and the three `YUV` data `DirectByteBuffers` are found in `image.getPlanes[]`, (with `Y` buffer always at index 0). Do I just pass in the `planes` array object of buffers, or do need to convert each buffer into a pixel array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to call the gallery. for that use this code.

```
private void callGallery() {
    if(newBitmap!=null){
    imageView=null;
}
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
         "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
```

And in onActivityResult

```
 if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         Uri selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
         //OI FILE Manager
         filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
         //MEDIA GALLERY
         selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
         scanQRImage(selectedImagePath);
     }
  }
protected void scanQRImage(String imagePath) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inScaled = true;
      options.inDensity = 240;// previously it was 240
      options.inTargetDensity = 240;//previously it was 240

      Bitmap bMap = scaleImage(imagePath);

      ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        view.setImageBitmap(bMap);

      LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap); 
      BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
      Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

      try {

           Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
           String contents = result.getText(); 
              byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); 
              BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
              ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
```

You will get the Result in contents string.

Comment: Thank you for the above code. But this would help me with picking a picture from the gallery, not through preview frames.

From what I understood, I have to use the following function for doing the preview frame part:

Comment: private void  decode(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Result rawResult = null;
    PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height);
    if (source != null) {
      BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
      try {
        rawResult = multiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
      } catch (ReaderException re) {
        // continue
      } finally {
        multiFormatReader.reset();
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height,null);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height), 80, baos);

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                    outStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    outStream.close();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
```

"the byte[] data provided by onPreviewFrame() is effectively
useless, because there is no efficient means of converting into a format
that the rest of Android understands" - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=823

So go ahead and convert your bytes into YuvImage inside the onPreview